# Yii 2.0 hidden field value not modifiable using javascript

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-components, yii2-advanced-app

In my model I have a hidden field.I am modifying its value using javascript (jQuery).But when I submit the form to model, it still contains its initial value instead of values modified via javascript.I have checked whether javascript is modifying the values, and is confirmed that values are being modified.But when form is submitted it is sending initial values.
Code is given below

```html
<?php
/*Model -- wrong_answers is my hidden field*/
namespace app\models;
use yii;
use yii\db;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class QuestionModel extends Model
{ 
    public $quiz_id = null; 
    public $question = '';
    public $choices = ''; 
    public $explanation ="";
    public $hints = array();
    public $correct_answer = "";
    public $wrong_answers = '{}';//when populating from already  entered data use {"a":"as"} format instead of {'a':'as'}
    public $wrong_answer = "";
    public function rules()
    {
    
        return [
            
            [['quiz_id'], 'safe']  , 
            [['question'], 'required']  ,  
            [['correct_answer'], 'required']  ,  
            [['wrong_answers'], 'safe']  ,      
            [['wrong_answer'], 'safe']  ,   
            [['explanation'],'required']
            
       ];
    }
    public function get_quiz($quiz_id) {
     $ret = array();
      $command =  Yii::$app->db->createCommand("CALL get_quiz(:qz_id)");
      $command->bindParam(":qz_id", $this->quiz_id);
       
      $result = $command->queryAll(); 
      if(sizeof($result) > 0)  {
       $ret = $result[0] ; 
       
      }
      return $ret;
        
    }
    public function save_question() {
    
     $ret = false;
     //echo "quiz- id is ".$this->quiz_id;
        $quiz_details = $this->get_quiz($this->quiz_id);
      if(sizeof($quiz_details)) {
        $quiz_data = $quiz_details['quiz_data'];
        $quiz_data   = json_decode($quiz_data); 
        $choices = [];
        echo $this->wrong_answers;
        exit;
        $wrong_answers_array = json_decode($this->wrong_answers);
        if($this->wrong_answer)
         array_push($wrong_answers_array, $this->wrong_answer);
         print_r($wrong_answers_array);
         exit;
        foreach($wrong_answers_array as $wr_ans) {
         array_push($choices,array('choice'=>$wr_ans));
        }
        $question_data = array('question'=>$this->question,'explanation'=>$this->explanation,'choices'=>$choices);
         $ret = false;     
      }        
      return $ret;
        
   
     
    }
    
    public function getHint($key) {
     return $this->hints[$key];
    }
    
}
```

> Controller - actionAdd_question is the action

```html
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter; 
use app\models\QuizModel;  
use app\models\QuestionModel;  
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

global $username;
class QuizController extends Controller
{ 
     
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    } 
    
     public function actionEntry()
    {
    }
     
    public function actionView_all() {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        $layout_params=array(
       'username'=>'admin',
       'sidebar_menu1_class' =>'active',
       'sidebar_menu12_class' =>'active',
       'dash_title' => 'Courses',
       'dash_sub_title'=>'View all'
       
      );
      
      $message = '';
      $data = array();
         $layout_params['scripts'] = array("view-all-modules.js");
         
         /*$model = new ViewAllCompaniesModel();
         $pagination_data = $model->getTotalCompanies();
          
         $layout_params['js_variables'] = array(
          'totalCompanyPages'=>$pagination_data['total_page_count'], 
          'csrfToken' => "'".$request->csrfToken."'" ,
          'csrfTokenName' => "'".$request->csrfParam."'"
         
         
         );
         */
       return $this->render('view-all-modules', [
             'layout_params'=>$layout_params,
             'message' =>$message,
             'data' =>$data
            ]);

    }
    
    public function actionAdd() {
              
     
      $layout_params=array(
       'username'=>'admin',
       'sidebar_menu1_class' =>'active',
       'sidebar_menu12_class' =>'active',
       'dash_title' => 'Quiz',
       'dash_sub_title'=>'Add new quiz'
       
      );
        $message = array();
        
        
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
     $proceed = true;
     $parent_course_id = null;
     $req_params  = $_POST;  
       
      

        $layout_params['scripts'] = array("add-quiz.js");
        
        $model  = new QuizModel(); 
         
         if(!$model->quiz_id) {
         
          if ($model->load($request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
                 $params = $request->post(); 
                
 
            
                    
               
                  $model->save_quiz();
          
           
                     
              
            
             
            
          
            $message['title'] = 'Wow !';
            $message['body'] = 'Successfully added quiz '.$model->quiz_title;
         
         
        } else {
         
        }
        } else {
         
        }
         
        
                  
      return $this->render('add-quiz', ['model' => $model,
             'layout_params'=>$layout_params,
             'message' =>$message
        ]);
        //return $this->render('add-company',$data);
    }
    public function actionSave() {
     //print_r($_POST);
    }
    public function actionAdd_question() {
     print_r($_POST);
     $layout_params=array(
       'username'=>'admin',
       'sidebar_menu1_class' =>'active',
       'sidebar_menu12_class' =>'active',
       'dash_title' => 'Quiz',
       'dash_sub_title'=>'Add question'
       
      );
       $request = Yii::$app->request;
        $message = array();
        $layout_params['scripts'] = array("add-question.js");
        
        $model  = new QuestionModel(); 
        
       if($request->get('q_id')) {
          $model->quiz_id = $request->get('q_id');
         if ($model->load($request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
                  $model->save_question();
            
                  
             } else {
              echo "yo yo";
             }
             return $this->render('add-question', ['model' => $model,
                   'layout_params'=>$layout_params,
                   'message' =>$message
                 ]);
       
       } else { 
       }
       
    }
    public function actionIndex()
    {         
     $data = array(
      'layout_params'=>array(
      'username'=>'admin',
      'sidebar_menu11_class' =>'active'
     )
     );//
    
  
         
    }
     public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }
 }
```

> View

```
    /*Assigning the parameters to be accessible by layouts*/

  foreach($layout_params as $layout_param => $value) {

      $this->params[$layout_param] = $value;

   }
   ?>

    <div class="form-group">

    </div>

<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header">
                  <h3 class="box-title">Add Question</h3>
                </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                <!-- form start -->


<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

                    <input type = 'hidden' id = 'test' name = 'test' />
                  <div class="box-body">
                  <?php if(isset($message)&&sizeof($message)): ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="callout callout-info  alert-dismissible">
                        <h4><?php if(isset($message['title']))echo $message['title'];?></h4>
                        <p>
                            <?php if(isset($message['body']))echo $message['body'];?>

                        </p>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif;?>

                    <div class="form-group"> 
                      <?= $form->field($model, 'question')->textInput(array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>
                    </div>





                    <div class="form-group">

                         <?= $form->field($model, 'correct_answer')->textInput(array("class"=>"form-control",'id'=>'correct_answer')); ?>
                        <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'wrong_answers',array('id'=>'wrong_answers')) ;?> 
                        <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'quiz_id',array('id'=>'quiz_id')) ;?> 

                     </div>  
                     <div class="form-group">

                         <?= $form->field($model, 'wrong_answer')->textInput(array("class"=>"form-control ",'id'=>'wrong_answer')); ?>
                          <button id = 'add-answer' type = "button">Add Another</button>
                        <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'wrong_answers',array('id'=>'wrong_answers')) ;?> 
                        <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'quiz_id',array('id'=>'quiz_id')) ;?> 

                     </div>  
                     <div class="form-group" id ='wrong-group'>
                         <h3>Wrong Answers</h3>
                         <!-- The following dummy html is used for generating html inside javascript -->
                         <ul class="edit-list-dummy" id ="edit-list-dummy">
                            <li> <button class="btn btn-danger" id = 'dummy-wrong-ans-delete' onClick = "deleteWrongAnswer(this.name)" type ="button">Delete</button>&nbsp;<span id ='dummy-wrong-answer'>Hello I am a wrong answer here</span>
                         </ul>
                         <ul class="edit-list"  id = 'wrong-answers'>
                          </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">

                         <?= $form->field($model, 'explanation')->textArea(array("class"=>"form-control",'id'=>'explanation')); ?>
                     </div>



                  </div><!-- /.box-body --> <div class="box-footer">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save Question', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary','onclick'=>'this.preventDefault']) ?>                            

                  </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>                
              </div>
</div>
```

> Javascript -#wrong_answers is my hidden input id

```html
var  wrongAnswers = {};//{1:answer1,2:answer2...};
var randCount = 0;//radom count for setting as wrongAnswers attribute
//initialise wrong answers json from database
$(document).ready(function() { 
    console.log($('#wrong_answers').val());
  wrongAnswers =  jQuery.parseJSON($('#wrong_answers').val());
  console.log(wrongAnswers);
  $('#add-answer').click(function() {
     var wrongAns = $('#wrong_answer').val().trim();
     if(wrongAns) {
         wrongAnswers[randCount] = wrongAns;
         randCount++;
         generateWrongAnswers();
         $('#wrong_answer').val("");
        // alert($('#wrong_answers').val());
     }
  });
  
  
  
   generateWrongAnswers(); 
    
      
}); 

function generateWrongAnswers() {
     
     $('#wrong-group').hide();
    var html = '';
    for(var wrongIdx in wrongAnswers) {
        //console.log("w is  ".wrongAnsIdx);
     $('#dummy-wrong-answer').html(wrongAnswers[wrongIdx]); 
     $('#dummy-wrong-ans-delete').attr('name',wrongIdx);
      
     html += $('#edit-list-dummy').html(); 
    }
    if(html) { 
        $('#wrong-group').show();
     $('#wrong-answers').html(html);
    }
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(wrongAnswers);
   
   $('#wrong_answers').val(jsonData);
   // $('#test').val(jsonData);
    //$('#correct_answer').val("Mallu");
   // alert($('#wrong_answers').val());
}
function deleteWrongAnswer(idx) {
    delete wrongAnswers[idx];
    generateWrongAnswers() ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finall solved it. The issue is that, I accidentally included two hidden input fields with same id.Removed one and solved